# Issue installing strongloop on Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2012, npm, strongloop, node-gyp, npm-install

After attempting to install strongloop, It threw a few warnings and errors.

Command used to install was: `npm install -g strongloop`

Errors:

```
c:\users\yoel\.node-gyp\4.2.4\include\node\v8.h(336): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition [C:\Users\Yoel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\heapdump\build\addon.vcxproj]
c:\users\yoel\.node-gyp\4.2.4\include\node\v8.h(336): error C2059: syntax error : 'using' [C:\Users\Yoel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\heapdump\build\addon.vcxproj]
c:\users\yoel\.node-gyp\4.2.4\include\node\v8.h(576): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'WeakCallbackType' [C:\Users\Yoel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_mododules\heapdump\build\addon.vcxproj]
c:\users\yoel\.node-gyp\4.2.4\include\node\v8.h(915): error C2989: 'v8::HandleScope' : class template has already been declared as a non-class template [C:\Users\Yoel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\heapdump\build\addon.vcxproj]
.
.
.
```

etc... [many of the same errors and a few others]

This is the error log form `builderror.log` :

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Yoel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\ws
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I am using Node 4.2.4, Python 2.7.11 and NPM 2.14.12

Things I've tried:

- reinstalling gyp
- reinstalling visual studio 2012
- installing strongloop with visual studio 2015
- installing strongloop with visual studio 2013
- installing strongloop with visual studio 2010

Any ideas? anyone else encountered a similar issue?

Note: I am able to run slc, but I have no way of knowing if everything works properly. It's not like a warning I can just ignore.

Comment: Try updating your version of Node-gyp `npm install -g node-gyp`

Comment: @bladefist are you sure the installation as a whole is failing? The error messages are for components that _should_ be optional and shouldn't cause the installation to fail.

Comment: @RyanGraham it sounds like you're right. but it's strange to have so many C compiling errors in an important component such as gyp.
It looks like node-gyp is installed correctly now.

Comment: Ya, it's unfortunate that Windows isn't as easy to develop and test on for module authors. The result is a lot of the popular modules with native addons don't build properly on Windows. The good news is a lot of them are optional and have pure JS fallbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has resolved the issue.

Step 1:
reinstall node-gyp to latest version: `npm install -g node-gyp`

Step 2:
run strongloop installation again like so: `npm install -g strongloop --msvs_version=2012`